# Pass a very large data in a link

Tags: javascript, url, electron

I am trying to open a link in electron and I need it to be opened in a default browser,
I know that there is shell.openexternal(url) which I can pass the url with the query string in it, but I want to pass a large data: the url which I want to open is a webpage and has a field which I want to fill it with this data, note that the webpage is something which I has no control on, I just have the link to it and I know about its query string. so passing the url with query string https://example.com?field_name=the_very_large_data&otherparameter=othervalue will not work I will get the error 400 bad request, because the header is too long.
My question is there a way to open an external link and to pass a very large data from the electron(to fill one of the page's field with the sent data)?

Comment: If that page breaks on `field_name` data size, then you can't do anything about it. There is server restrictions on size of parameters.

Comment: HTTP Post method ?

Comment: since I am using the shell.openexternal I think I cant make it post .. I will consider form submit to do post @darkomen

Comment: @Justinas okay thanx